# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154

Tags: wcf, com, windows-7, iis-7.5, dcom

I am running 32 bit Windows 7 Operation System which has IIS 7.5 installed.

In Visual Studio 2010, I open my solution having the web site project hosting WCF service. I have created an application in the IIS which points to the website project. The web site's bin folder has many assemblies which I need to refer. But those assemblies also have built using .NET 4 on the same computer.

I can browse the WCF service using both HTTP & HTTPS.

However, when i access the service from the test windows application (using the proxy class of the WCF contract), I get the error in question. Everything was working without problem earlier.

Anyone can help to fix the issue?. How to investigate this issue?

Comment: @dlev: Using the WCF proxy class. Updated this in question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 0x80040154 means "Class Not Registered", which usually means you're depending on a COM component that hasn't been installed properly on the machine.

Is any of those Assemblies you reference a COM Interop Assembly? If so, find out what it uses and then install the appropriate COM component.

Comment: Thanks. It was referencing some COM component which was not registered. Just for information which might help others: If you run the 'dcomcnfg' command from the Start Menu -> Run, you will see the Configuration Manager. If you switch it to "Details" you, you can see the CLSID for all the installed components. This is how you can verify whether the component (you get CLSID in the error) for which it's complaining is already installed or not. If installed, you can check it's permissions additionally.

Comment: @CSharpLearner I haven't thought of the *Component Services* which helped! Thanks a million.